# Hit Break Point Goes Upward Blazor Server

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a Language dropdown in Blazor layout that finally calls this method:

```
private async Task SetLanguage(string lang)
{
    cultureChanger.ChangeCulture(lang);
    await GetLanguageValues();        
}
```

The GetLanguageValues() method should be called then, But the debugger does not step over cultureChanger.ChangeCulture(lang); and then goes out of the method to the caller. How do I solve this?

GetLanguageValues method:

```
string lang = "";   

private async Task GetLanguageValues()
{
    lang = textService.GetText(cultureChanger.Current, "lang");
    ViewData.Language = lang;

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

CultureChanger class:

```
public class CultureChanger
{
    public CultureInfo Current { get; private set; } = new CultureInfo("en");

    public event Action OnCultureChange;

    public void ChangeCulture(string cultureName)
    {
        Current = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
        OnCultureChange?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

I am upgrading a preview 6 Blazor project to preview 9, Previously it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

One of the components that subscribe to this event had StateHasChanged() in its method that I replaced with: base.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);